# JavaFX MediaPlayer not playing with JDK 10

Tags: java, javafx

I am just trying to play a mp3 file using JavaFX with JDK 10.

I only have 1 main Java file. **The code works with JDK 8 but not JDK 10.** When running with JDK 10, I compiled with the `--add-modules=javafx.graphics,javafx.media` flag and it can run, showing the window but no audio is being played.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.File;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
        String bip = "bip.mp3";
        Media hit = new Media(new File(bip).toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        ((Group)scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

How to make MediaPlayer work with JDK 10? Otherwise, any idea what may be the cause of this issue?

Comment: System.out the result of `new File(bip).toURI().toString()`, I'm going to make a guess that does not contain the correct path to the filename you hardcoded.

Comment: Could you try to play a .wav File or something? Maybe it's a missing mp3 decoder because of licensing issues?

Comment: See if you get any errors by listening to the [`error` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#errorProperty).

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue to the album art of the mp3 which was generated from photoshop (cos sometimes I photoshop album art). The code works with other mp3 files that doesnt have album art or the album art wasnt photoshopped. @Slaw how to listen to the error property?

Comment: Add an `InvalidationListener` or a `ChangeListener` to the property and react appropriately. You could also use the `onError` property. Basically, observe the `MediaPlayer` (or `Media`) for errors and print the stack trace of the `MediaException` if one occurs.